# Keyboard shortcuts don't work for intelliJ

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, intellij

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, Xenial with KDE. System is in German, I have Cherry Keyboard in German layout and I can't use IntelliJ keyboard shortcut.

For example, with "Comment with Block Comment" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, this combo doesn't work with German layout. I tried to change Keymap in IntelliJ as in screenshot, but nothing works

[image]

Any suggestions much appreciated .

Comment: In 18.04 and Gnome it happens as well.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an old issue in IntelliJ: [Keyboard layout stop switching sometimes](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6290)

The current workaround is to change **Input Sources** order in **Settings** -> **Region & Language** and put your desired layout first. No IntelliJ restart required.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (under Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome) and resolved it by uninstalling the english keyboard layout. I went to settings -> region & languages . There I had both, the German Layout and the English Layout as input sources. I removed the English input source.

Comment: This content is too less as an answer, so this answer needs to be made as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> in OS as layout change keys combination, for example.

Try using <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> to separate OS and Intellij key listeners. In this case more general <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> will work for the right side keys combination in IDE: <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a issue with just useing the `Right Ctrl` for commenting for example.

Since I use ubuntu in **Oracle VM Virtual Box**, the `Right Ctrl` is set as a hotkey for VBox so it's not working in other programs such as Intellij.
I changed the setting in Oracle VBox and then Right Ctrl worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Keyboard Shortcuts are on the Ubuntu "Settings" app. In my case, a Gnome extension I've installed (GPaste) defined several keyboard shortcuts which conflicted with mine. It took me a long time to notice it, since most of the actions were silent.

Answer (score 0):

Depending from concrete user situation (for example you have <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> turned on or you changed to different from English language keyboard layout) it can happen if you have turn on **☑ Use national layouts for shortcuts** option turned on.

[image: Settings dialog opened on the page where Use national layouts for shortcuts provided]

So you need turn that option off. You can uncheck it in **Settings** dialog by going to `Settings -> Keymap` or by editing IDE VM options file directly by putting `-Dcom.sun.awt.use.national.layouts=false` or replacing `-Dcom.sun.awt.use.national.layouts=true` to `-Dcom.sun.awt.use.national.layouts=false`. You can open that file directly from IDE in menu `Help -> Edit custom VM options`

[image: PHP IDE VM options file with -Dcom.sun.awt.use.national.layouts=false inserted there]